# How to get the class name with parent function in jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes, parent, eventhandler

How can I get  `'field_wrapper_1'` class name while clicking the function `addIncludeTextBox`?

```
<div class="field_wrapper_1">
        <span class="error php-error" id="php-error_includes" style="display: none"></span> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <div class="form_group">
                <label class="form_label">Includes <span>*</span></label>
                <input class="form_input" name="includes[][]" id="includes" placeholder="Enter the details of fees includes" type="text">                                    

            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 3.6%;" class="col-md-1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" onclick="addIncludeTextBox(this)" title="Add field"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(obj).closest('[class^=field_wrapper]').attr("class")
```

Combine `.closest` and `.attr` to get the class.

*Optional* you can also just use `.closest('.field_wrapper_1')`

**Working demo**

```js
function addIncludeTextBox(obj){
  console.log($(obj).closest('[class^=field_wrapper]').attr("class"))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_wrapper_1">
        <span class="error php-error" id="php-error_includes" style="display: none"></span> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <div class="form_group">
                <label class="form_label">Includes <span>*</span></label>
                <input class="form_input" name="includes[][]" id="includes" placeholder="Enter the details of fees includes" type="text">                                    

            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 3.6%;" class="col-md-1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" onclick="addIncludeTextBox(this)" title="Add field"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">+</i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```